# Random port connection while portscan

Tags: c, linux, sockets, port-scanning

I've made a very basic port-scan program in C to scan a port range. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HOST "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 4444

int createConnection(const char *host[], const int port)
{
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int sock = 0;
    int ret;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
    {
        printf("Error %d socket creating.\n", sock);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        memset(&server_addr, '0', sizeof(server_addr));

        server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
        ret = inet_pton(AF_INET, host, &server_addr.sin_addr);
        if (ret <= 0)
        {
            printf("Error %d unsuported address: %d\n", ret);
            return -2;
        }
        else
        {
            ret = connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
            if (ret < 0)
            {
                //printf("[-] Port %d closed.\n", port);
                close(sock);
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("[+] Port %d open.\n", port);
                close(sock);
                return 0;
            }
        }

    }
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 65536; i++)
    {
        createConnection("127.0.0.1", i);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the for loop, it scans from port 1 to port 65535. The problem is that when I start it, I get this output:

```
[+] Port 42178 open.
[+] Port 48650 open.
[+] Port 60078 open.
```

The "open ports" always change, but are always superior to 40000. But, I checked with `netstat -tulpn`, only my port 68 is open for the dhclient, which is UDP and not TCP. Why does it say that I have open ports ?

Comment: `const char *host[]` ==> `const char *host` or `const char host[]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I suspect you're running into your open socket *source* ports while scanning.**

TCP connections have a source port. If one is not assigned to a socket (via `bind`), then the kernel assigns an *ephemeral* port (in the high range) to the socket when you call `connect`, before the SYN is sent.

Since you are connecting your sockets to your local machine, as you loop through the destination ports, it is possible that the kernel will assign a random ephemeral source port that happens to match the same destination port to which you're about to connect.

See:

- [Linux/Unix Socket Self-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16767113/119527)
- [Socket getting created with same IP and port on local host](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4021271/119527)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !